# JobLauncherCommandLineRunner: running default command line with: [] fails my JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch, batch-processing

I've been searching for answers on this but to no avail. So I'm posting this.

Whenever I start my spring batch JUnit tests, this job with empty parameter always run:

```
2016-04-02 06:04:00,262  INFO 3651 [main] [] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner - Running default command line with: []
```

Which breaks my tests and thus I cannot build my application:

```
2016-04-02 06:04:00,262  INFO 3651 [main] [] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner - Running default command line with: []
2016-04-02 06:04:00,521  INFO 3651 [main] [] o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/ec2-user/workspace/efs-mi3-daily-recon-batch/target/surefire/surefirebooter4799221294694718787.jar, file:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar]
2016-04-02 06:04:00,521  INFO 3651 [main] [] o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-04-02 06:04:00,522 ERROR 3651 [main] [] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:675)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=4860, version=0, Job=[reconJob]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at
```

I figured, if I delete all related job entries in the batch tables, the app will build successfully. I already deleted all the `BATCH_` table entries for the job ID 4860. However I still get the error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=4860, version=0, Job=[reconJob]
```

Thoughts?

EDIT: How can I prevent the JUnit test to run the `Running default command line with: []`

Comment: please add the test in question

Comment: @MichaelPralow I think I got it. I explicitly specified the job name to run. The job test now doesn't execute the job with `{[]}` parameter which is what I want to happen. Thanks!

Comment: @makalshrek how did you specify job name explicitly? Can you please tell?